# React.js: how to decouple jsx out of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way to move the jsx from a component's render function to a separate file? If so, how do I reference the jsx in the render function?

Comment: do you use browserify? then you can just write 'exports = <div />' in a file

Comment: What's your motivation in doing that? The `render` method is heavily tied to the logic in the rest of the component. All templating frameworks are just as heavily coupled, e.g. your rendering code must know the exact variable names your template expects, and Render decided to keep them together.

Comment: i like having the template(jsx) separate from the view(js)

Comment: I am also working on a project using ReactJS. I needed to divide my code in different files to have more manageable and clean code. I used RequireJS to achieve that. You can read about it here: [Using ReactJS with RequireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381561/using-reactjs-with-requirejs/).
Hope it helps.

Comment: I use Eclipse, so my editor doesn't work if I mix jsx markup into my code. Also I don't want to mix markup into my code just because this happens to be the recommended approach. It still seems crazy to me. At any rate, this is a perfectly valid question and the React documentation always says that it is optional to put jsx in your code so asking "why would you want to do that?" seems unhelpful.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It ruins the entire concept of React.

Comment: see above. Also, this prevents developers from littering the jsx with 'this.foo()' everywhere. Just add all the fields to state in componentWillUpdate, and in render, return 'myJSX(this.props, this.state)'

Comment: @sarink Why does it ruin the entire concept? When you have an IDE that makes it easy to quickly write out HTML you have to give all that up in order to write it all in one file - that is VERY annoying.

Comment: How is writing html, or the capabilities of your ide, at all relevant to this conversation? A React Component is a javascript class, and render is one of its functions. It's all 100% javascript! JSX is simply syntactic sugar (it is _not_ html!).... If you don't like it, and you're perfectly happy with your html templates, then why did you choose React? Furthermore, the concept of React is to compose components. So there is literally zero value in externalizing the contents of the render function, because it is unusable anywhere else. Just render <TheComponent> in another Component's render()!

Comment: If this is of interest to you, then Vue.js might be for you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a pattern for separating the template jsx that uses CommonJS modules in NodeJS, Browserify or Webpack. In NodeJS, I found the node-jsx module helpful to avoid the need to compile the JSX.

```
// index.js
require('node-jsx').install({extension: '.jsx'});
var React = require('react'),
    Component = require('./your-component');


// your-component.jsx
var YourComponent,
    React = require('react'),
    template = require('./templates/your-component.jsx');

module.exports = YourComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return template.call(this);
  }
});


// templates/your-component.jsx
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('react');

module.exports = function() {

  return (
    <div>
      Your template content.
    </div>
  );

};
```

Update 2015-1-30: incorporated suggestion in Damon Smith's answer to set `this` in the template function to the React component.

Update 12/2016: the current best practice is to use the .js extension and use a build tool like Babel to output the final javascript from your source. Take a look at [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) if you're just getting started. Also, the latest React best practices do recommend a separation between components that manage state (typically called "container components") and components that are presentational. These presentational components can now be written as functions, so they are not far off from the template function used in the previous example. Here is how I would recommend decoupling most of the presentational JSX code now. These examples still use the [ES5 `React.createClass()` syntax](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html).

```
// index.js
var React = require('react'),
    ReactDOM = require('react-dom'),
    YourComponent = require('./your-component');

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(YourComponent, {}, null),
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// your-component.js
var React = require('react'),
    YourComponentTemplate = require('./templates/your-component');

var YourComponentContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      color: 'green'
    };
  },

  toggleColor: function() {
    this.setState({
      color: this.state.color === 'green' ? 'blue' : 'green'
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    var componentProps = {
      color: this.state.color,
      onClick: this.toggleColor
    };
    return <YourComponentTemplate {...componentProps} />;
  }
});

module.exports = YourComponentContainer;

// templates/your-component.js
var React = require('react');

module.exports = function YourComponentTemplate(props) {
  return (
    <div style={{color: props.color}} onClick={props.onClick}>
      Your template content.
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work if you use other components in your template

Comment: I think your template should be able to require the other components. No?

Comment: @Shivam it would work if your template function didn't need to access `this.props` or `this.state`. I just updated the answer with an additional example that shows the current best practices in React for separating components into pure functional components used for presentational templates and container components that manage state.

Answer (score 29):

You can use [react-templates](https://github.com/wix/react-templates). It gives you exactly this separation between the markup and the component itself, and much more.

I found it very useful for my needs (a large scale web app).

Comment: Exactly this. React templates also provides a lot of useful features like `if`s `repeat`s and other misc.

Answer (score 28):

One problem with moving templates into a separate file is that if you use handlers like:

```
var myTemplate = (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}></form>
);
```

and then in your component you use:

```
render: function() {
    return myTemplate;
}
```

the generated template code will call this.handleSubmit(), so the "this" will be wrong and the handlers won't work. What you need to do is put them in a function, like this:

```
var myTemplate = function() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}></form>
    );
};
```

then in your component's render function, you need to bind it to 'this' correctly, then call it, like this:

```
render: function() {
    return myTemplate.bind(this)();
},
```

Now you can put that template definition anywhere, in a separate file or however you want to structure and reference your own code. (power to you! Don't listen to these crazy prescriptive frameworks! :) )

Comment: Good tip; one suggestion: you could just call `myTemplate.call(this)` (no need for `bind()`, which creates a new function).

Answer (score 13):

I just separated JSX into anonymous function files

**template.js**

```
export default (component) => {
return <h1>Hello {component.props.name}</h1>
}
```

**my-component.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import template from './template';

export default MyComponent extends Component {
   render() {
     return template(this);
   }
}
```

In template you can access props or state or functions using `component` variable.

Comment: what about css loader,image loader etc?

Comment: What about for a functional component...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use any module system, i.e. rely on `script` tags only, simple expose your JSX component in a global variable and use it when you need :

```
// component.js
var Component = React.createClass({ /* your component */ });
// main.js
React.renderComponent(Component({}), domNode);
```

Note : the `script` tag for *component.js* must appear before the `script` tag for *main.js.*

If you use a Commonjs-like module system like Browserify, simply export your component definition and require it when you need it.

```
// component.js
var React = require("react");
module.exports = React.createClass({ /* your component */ });
// main.js
var Component = require("component.js");
React.renderComponent(Component({}), domNode);
```