# Using reactjs with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, frontend, reactjs

Recently, I started using `reactjs` along with a `backbonejs` router to build an application.

I usually use use `requirejs` for dependency and code management. But, problem arises when I try to include files that contain `jsx` syntax.

This is what I have so far as my `router.js`:

```
define(["backbone", "react"], function(Backbone, React) {

  var IndexComponent = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
      return (
        <div>
        Some Stuff goes here
        </div>
        );
    }
  });



  return Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {
      "": "index"
    },
    index : function() {
      React.renderComponent(<IndexComponent />, document.getElementById('index'));
    }
  });
});
```

How do I put IndexComponent in its own file and call it in this file ? I have tried the usual method (the same that I have used with backbone and react) but got an error due to `jsx` syntax.

Comment: question- do you need to use JSX or could you just use straight JS in the app?

Comment: That's completely upto you. JSX makes life easier, but you could still use JS syntax components. Read about it here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/displaying-data.html#react-without-jsx

Comment: you may also wish to call return new Backbone.Router

Answer (score 105, accepted):

So I figured it out myself.

I got the necessary files and instructions from this repo: [jsx-requirejs-plugin](https://github.com/philix/jsx-requirejs-plugin).

Once I had [jsx plugin](https://raw.github.com/philix/jsx-requirejs-plugin/master/js/jsx.js) and modified version of [JSXTransformer](https://raw.github.com/alirussell/jsx-requirejs-plugin/master/js/JSXTransformer-0.10.0.js), I changed my code as instructed in the repository :

```
require.config({
  // ...

  paths: {
    "react": "path/to/react",
    "JSXTransformer": "path/to/JSXTransformer",
    "jsx": "path/to/jsx plugin"
    ...
  }

  // ...
});
```

Then, I could reference JSX files via the `jsx!` plugin syntax. For example, to load the Timer.jsx file that is in a components directory:

```
require(['react', 'jsx!components/Timer'], function (React, Timer) {
   ...
   React.renderComponent(<Timer />, document.getElementById('timer'));
   ...
});
```

I could also access `.js` files that had `jsx` syntax in them using the same code:

```
require(['react', 'jsx!components/Timer'], function (React, Timer) {
   ...
   React.renderComponent(<Timer />, document.getElementById('timer'));
   ...
});
```

Also, I did not need to put `/** @jsx React.DOM */` at the top of files using `jsx` syntax.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Kind of puzzled by the code snippet under "I could also access .js files that had jsx syntax in them using the same code:".  It's identical to the one above it.  I found that if I was using JSX inside a require module, I needed to make that same module a jsx file too (and load using the jsx plugin like you said).  Could you update your sample to be a little more clear on how you've organized *your* code as opposed to just the react/jsx code.  For example, what does your Timer module look like?  What name do you give to the module that uses Timer and how is it loaded with require?

Comment: In the first instance, it is assumed that `Timer` uses `jsx` syntax and has a `.jsx` extension. In the second instance, although the code is same, it is assumed that `Timer` again contains `jsx` syntax but has a `.js` extension.

Comment: Doesn't work, requirejs isn't downloading the files with no errors or 404s.

Comment: Is this answer appropriate for 2018? I can't find the recommended way to load React via requirejs after 2016.

Answer (score 4):

React tools (JSX included) have been deprecated in favor of Babel (https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html). I cannot find a way to do this without a "transpiling" step, so this is my solution with grunt.

You can instal grunt-babel (npm install grunt-babel) and configure a task like the following:

```
babel: {
    options: {
        sourceMap: false,
        modules: "common"
    },
    dist: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: ['js/components/*.jsx'],
            dest: 'dist',
            ext:'.js'
       }]
    }
}
```

Just add it to your list of grunt tasks:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'copy', 'babel', 'http-server']);
```

Babel will transpile your JSX to JS files that can be specified as RequireJS dependencies with no additional configuration.

Comment: thank you for the grunt piece ,i have implemented something same ,but after my jsx code is bablified ,the browser throws requirejs not available error.Can you suggest some solution?