# React Component with RequireJS

Tags: reactjs, requirejs

I am a beginner in react.js and i have to re implement another system in react.js. The other system uses RequireJS and I am not sure how to include it in a react component.

My render code looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown'
import 'react-dropdown/style.css'
import Neo4jDBService from "../../api/Neo4jDBService";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

class WelcomeComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super (props)
        this.handleSucessfulResponse = this.handleSucessfulResponse.bind(this)
        this.handleErrorResponse = this.handleErrorResponse.bind(this)

        this.state ={
            letter : [],
            selected: '',
            welcomeMessage : '',

        }
    }



    componentDidMount() {

        console.log('didmount');
        this.getLetterNames();
    }

    getLetterNames(){
        console.log('filter')
        var counter = 0;

        Neo4jDBService.retrieveAllLetterNames()
            .then( response => {
                response.data.map (data => {

                    console.log(data)
                })
                this.setState({letter: response.data})

            });

    }
    initEditor(){

    }

    render() {
        console.log('draw');
        return (

            <div>
                <Helmet>
                    <title>Editor</title>
                    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
                    <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
                    <meta name="viewport"
                          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
                    <meta content="" name="description"/>
                    <meta content="" name="author"/>
                    <link href="/../../standoff-properties-editor-master/css/bootstrap.min.css"  type="text/css"/>
                    <link href="/../../standoff-properties-editor-master/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"  type="text/css"/>
                    <link href="/../../standoff-properties-editor-master/css/font-awesome.css"  type="text/css"/>

                    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
                    <link href="/../../standoff-properties-editor-master/css/app/editor.css"  type="text/css"/>

                </Helmet>

        <body style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
            <div style={{display: 'none'}} id="modal-nav"></div>
         <section id="main-template">
            <div data-bind="template: { name: 'text-edit-part-template', data: $data }"></div>
          </section>

        <script src="../../standoff-properties-editor-master/scripts/require.js"></script>
        <script src="../../standoff-properties-editor-master/scripts//app/app.require.config.js"></script>
        <script type="text/html" id="text-edit-part-template">
            <div className="container" style={{marginTop: '40px'}}>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <label>
                            File
                        </label>
                        <div className="input-group">
                            <select className="form-control" data-bind="value: $data.file, options: $data.files, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'value'"></select>
                            <span className="input-group-btn">
                            <button className="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $data.loadClicked">Load</button>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div className="row" style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <div>
                                    <label>
                                        Annotations
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <button style={{borderBottom: '3px solid red'}} data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Person"
                                        className="btn btn-default tip" data-bind="click: $data.personClicked"><span className="fa fa-user"></span></button>
                                <button style={{borderBottom: '3px solid pink'}} data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Place"
                                        className="btn btn-default tip" data-bind="click: $data.placeClicked"><span className="fa fa-map"></span></button>
                                <button style={{borderBottom: '3px solid cyan'}} data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Date"
                                        className="btn btn-default tip" data-bind="click: $data.dateClicked"><span className="fa fa-clock-o"></span></button>
                                <button style={{borderBottom: '3px solid blue'}} data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Event"
                                        className="btn btn-default tip" data-bind="click: $data.eventClicked"><span className="fa fa-calendar"></span></button>
                                <button style={{borderBottom: '3px solid green'}} data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Concept"
                                        className="btn btn-default tip" data-bind="click: $data.conceptClicked"><span className="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></span></button>
                                <button style={{borderBottom: '3px solid yellow'}} data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Text"
                                        className="btn btn-default tip" data-bind="click: $data.textClicked"><span className="fa fa-file-text"></span></button>
                                <button style={{borderBottom: '3px solid lightgreen'}} data-toggle="tooltip"
                                        data-original-title="Web Link" className="btn btn-default tip" data-bind="click: $data.webLinkClicked"><span
                                    className="fa fa-link"></span></button>
                                <button style={{borderBottom: '3px solid yellow'}} data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Footnotes"
                                        className="btn btn-default tip" data-bind="click: $data.footnoteClicked"><span style={{fontWeight: 600}}>f</span></button>
                                <button style={{borderBottom: '3px solid purple'}} data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Domain" className="btn btn-default tip" data-bind="click: $data.domainClicked"><span>|</span></button>
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-md-2" style={{paddingTop: '20px', paddingLeft: '40px'}}>
                                <label>Expansions</label>
                                <input data-bind="checked: $data.checkbox.expansions" type="checkbox"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div className="row" style={{marginTop: '10px'}}>
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <div data-role="editor" spellCheck="false" contentEditable="true" className="editor"></div>
                                <div data-role="monitor" className="form-control monitor"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row" style={{marginTop: '10px'}}>
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <button className="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: $data.cancelClicked">Cancel</button>
                                <button className="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $data.saveClicked">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <button className="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $data.unbindClicked">Unbind</button>
                                <button className="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $data.bindClicked">Bind</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row" style={{marginTop: '10px'}}>
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <textarea className="form-control" rows="5" data-bind="value: $data.viewer"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>
        dsfdsffsdfsdsfd
        </body>
                <script>
                    var editor;
                    require(["part/text-edit", "jquery"], function (Editor, $) {

                    //
                    // This ensures that tooltips are applied to all targets, whether or not they are dynamically created.
                    //
                    $("body").tooltip({
                        selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
                    });
                    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                    var file = urlParams.get("file");
                    var node = document.getElementById("main-template");
                    $.get(file, function (json) {
                    var editor = new Editor({
                    template: node,
                    editor: json
                });
                    editor.applyBindings(node);
                });



                });
                </script>
    </div>

        )
    }

    handleSucessfulResponse(response) {
        this.setState({welcomeMessage: response.data.message})
    }

    handleErrorResponse(error) {
      //console.log(error.response);
         this.setState({welcomeMessage: error.response.data.message})
    }

}

export default WelcomeComponent
```

However, I get the following error message:

./src/components/todo/WelcomeComponent.jsx
Line 172:23:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"

170 |                     $("body").tooltip({
171 |                         selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'

> 172 |                     });
> |                       ^
> 173 |                     var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
> 174 |                     var file = urlParams.get("file");
> 175 |                     var node = document.getElementById("main-template");

Where and how can I use/integrate the

```
                    var editor;
                    require(["part/text-edit", "jquery"], function (Editor, $) {

                    //
                    // This ensures that tooltips are applied to all targets, whether or not they are dynamically created.
                    //
                    $("body").tooltip({
                        selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
                    });
                    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                    var file = urlParams.get("file");
                    var node = document.getElementById("main-template");
                    $.get(file, function (json) {
                    var editor = new Editor({
                    template: node,
                    editor: json
                });
                    editor.applyBindings(node);
                });



                });
                </script>
```

script function into my React component? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using reactjs with requirejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381561/using-reactjs-with-requirejs)

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response. I also found this entry, but I'm not sure if the require call is in the right place and how I can get my code into React.render function. Can you give me a little starter help?

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to require your dependencies ahead of time.  Maybe switch to typescript and make the entire project use AMD modules.  You are mixing ES modules with AMD modules.  [Here](https://github.com/ca0v/react-lab) is a react project written in typescript that uses AMD and it defines a couple [components](https://github.com/ca0v/react-lab/tree/master/components).