# RequireJs with Babel

Tags: reactjs, requirejs, babeljs

I'm trying to implement project with ReactJs + RequireJs. I'm able to load React Components with React and Babel library as [given example](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). Now I'm trying to use the same React Components  with RequireJs. But getting error as **unexpected token '<' at line babel-scripts.js:3**

Here is my code below :

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>New project</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/core/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/core.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">        
        <script crossorigin src="./assets/core/lib/reactjs/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script data-main = "./modules/babel-scripts" src = "./assets/core/lib/require/require.js"></script>
        <script src = "./modules/require-config.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**require-config.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'react': '../assets/core/lib/reactjs/react.development',
        'react-dom': '../assets/core/lib/reactjs/react-dom.development',
        // 'babel': '../assets/core/lib/reactjs/babel.min',
        'jquery': '../assets/core/lib/jquery/jquery-3.5.1.min',
        'bootstrap': '../assets/core/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min',
        'header': './header'
    }
});
```

**babel-scripts.js**

```
requirejs(['jquery', 'react', 'react-dom', 'header'], function($, React, ReactDOM, Header) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Header />, document.getElementById('root')
    );
});
```

**header.js**

```
requirejs(['jquery', 'react', 'react-dom'], function($, React, ReactDOM) {
    return React.createClass( {
        render: function () {
            return(<div>hi....</div>)
        }
    });
});
```

I guess the issue is with babel library which is not implemented properly. Tried a lot to fix it but couldn't get proper output. Please do suggest your input. Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS loads modules asynchronously as text, after load, the code is executed. The problem here is that your file `babel-scripts.js` does not contain valid JavaScript, it is JSX.

There are two possible options:

1. Translate JSX to valid JavaScript. It can be done by Babel and other tools
2. Translate JSX on the fly via RequireJS plugin, this topic is already covered on SO: [Using reactjs with requirejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381561/using-reactjs-with-requirejs)